# Get Org URL from Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning

I am operating in an org: `https://myorg.lightning.force.com`.  If I call `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()` from an apex class I get the base org URL back.  If I then use the same command in a controller for a lightning component in a community I get the community's base URL: `https://mycommunity.aa11.force.com`.

Any ideas on how I can get the Org URL (`https://myorg.lightning.force.com`) in a lightning component dynamically?

Comment: We can always use **Custom Metadata Types** to store a static data and use across the org. For more information, please refer to: [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US). You just need to query it in your Apex controller class, and refer in the Lightning's JS controller class.

Comment: This is what I've done for now, created a custom setting and retrieved it in the apex, not ideal as it adds another step for setting up a new org but the only way I could solve it for now.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for reviving an old post, but I was trying to find the same answer as OP and wanted to provide my solution for anyone else who might stumble upon this post:

```
   public static String getLexOriginUrl() {
        String prefix = URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm().replace('https://', '').split('\\.')[0];
        prefix = prefix.removeEnd('--c');
        return 'https://' + prefix.toLowerCase() + '.lightning.force.com';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

String Host = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/';

This will return https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/

then you can pass this to your controller.js file and use it.
Hope this answer your question

Comment: This doesn't work as the comments on glls answer say.

Comment: yes in that case it might not.. :)

Comment: its better to raise a case in salesforce support and ask them only.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reference the apex class as your server side controller and fetch the value on the client side?

Server side controller:

```
public with sharing class theorgurl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String fetchit(){
        string urler = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toString();
        return (urler);
    }
}
```

Client side controller:

```
"geturl" : function(cmp) {

        var action = cmp.get("c.fetchit");
        action.setParams({ urlname : cmp.get("v.urlname") });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
             ...Do something with response.getReturnValue()...
        }
}
```

If you are unsure on how to proceed, I would recommend you go through the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_intro.htm) since

> the framework supports client-side and server-side controllers.

Comment: This is exactly what I said didn't work, the URL.getSalesforceBaseURL() when called from a community context returns the base URL for the community, not the main org.

Comment: Sorry, your question was not completely clear, nor was your approach.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to get your org URL without APEX, use:

```
let hostname = window.location.hostname;
```

Comment: I think this is the only simple and efficient way to find the lightning base URL

Comment: This may have worked in the past, but today in LWC `window.location.hostname` returns `undefined`. Security has been tightened again. Stop having fun. 