# Get the salesforce org url when user has logged in into communities

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

The user is logged in into a community and there is a requirement to send a mail containing a link to the contact record of this user. So basically the need here is to get the salesforce org url (not community url) in the lightning component apex controller. Note: This URL should be got dynamically.

Had gone through various stites including the current  with no solutions-
1)[Get Org URL Via Web Service](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191814/get-org-url-via-web-service)
2)[Get Org URL from Lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184774/get-org-url-from-lightning-component)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to get Org URL in Community.you need to pass community/NtworkId.

```
Network.getLoginUrl('Community id');
```

or Use

```
String servUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
```